# How many PWM output channels does the Atmega4809 really have?

Tags: avr, pwm, atmega

How many PWM outputs does the Atmega4809 really have? The Microchip site claims it has 8.

The datasheet for the Atmega4809 microcontroller is split up into two pdfs. [This one](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40002015A.pdf) is for the megaAVR family. It describes the timer configuration for generic timers used in PWM. [This one](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40002016A.pdf) describes a few specifics of the pin layout for the Atmega4809.

For PWM, the Atmega4809 has:

- One 16-bit Timer/Counter type A with dedicated period register, three compare channels (TCA)
- Four 16-bit Timer/Counter type B with input capture (TCB)
- One 16-bit Real Time Counter (RTC) running from external crystal or internal RC oscillator

From what I understand, the one TCA timer has PWM 3 output channels and TCB timers each have only one output channel. That makes 7 PWM output channels. Does that mean the real-time counter (RTC) can be configured as a PWM output?

Comment: Correct. The RTC has a compare match unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where does the number 8 come from, but I can see total of 10 possible PWM outputs in the datasheet.

The RTC has no easy & direct way how to create PWM output.

On the other hand TCA timer can be run in split 8bit mode. Citing from the megaAVR family datasheet, page 193:

> Split Mode Overview To double the number of timers and PWM channels in
>   the TCA, a Split mode is provided. In this Split mode, the 16-bit
>   timer/counter acts as two separate 8-bit timers, which each have three
>   compare channels for PWM generation. The Split mode will only work
>   with single-slope down-count. Split mode does not support event action
>   controlled operation.

You can enable this mode by setting bit 0 in `CTRLD` register. The meaning of `CTRLB` register changes then and you can enable all 6 outputs there. So, if it is acceptable to have 8bit only PWM with common clock source for all 6 channels, you can use this mode.

Atmega4809 datasheet shows, in page 8, which pins can be outputs of TCA0 mapped to.

TCB timers add 4 PWM channels, one for each counter.

If you really need more PWM channels, it is *maybe* possible to get one or few more (in a bit hacky way) through the custom logic unit. Use suitable source of periodic events (maybe the RTC?) to flip an output of CCL as needed.

Comment: On page 8, it appears "0-WOn" means TCA0 wave ouput n, where n is from 0 to 5. To select which pins those outputs are connected to, do you use the TCAROUTEA register?

Comment: Yes, you can choose particular port in this way (all six TCA outputs have to be pins 0 to 5 of one and the same port always).